# How do I get a response from REST API in JSON format in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, json

I used the resources in “[Creating a New REST Web Service in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86395/create-custom-rest-api-in-magento2-and-solution-for-invalidargumentexception-e/86424)” and “[Creating a New REST Web Service in Magento 2](http://alankent.me/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/)” to create a custom API module, but the response is in XML format. I need a response in JSON format with key value pairs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 18):

Below are the custom api module with key pair value
To get JSON response, in client set Response headers to `"Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"`

and if you need key pair value that is in response should have key and value as like `/rest/V1/categories` we need to create data interface

To test in Chrome download plugin called rest client app call the url

below module url will be http://yourdomein.com/magento2/rest/V1/getinfo

**app\code\Sugarcode\Customapi\registration.php**:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sugarcode_Customapi',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app\code\Sugarcode\Customapi\etc\module.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sugarcode_Customapi" setup_version="2.0.0"/>
</config>
```

**app\code\Sugarcode\Customapi\etc\di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\TestInterface"
                type="Sugarcode\Customapi\Model\Test" />

    <preference for="Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\Data\TestdataInterface" type="Sugarcode\Customapi\Model\Testmodel" />
</config>
```

**app\code\Sugarcode\Customapi\etc\webapi.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">

    <!-- Example: curl http://127.0.0.1/index.php/rest/V1/calculator/add/1/2 -->
    <route url="/V1/getinfo" method="GET">
        <service class="Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\TestInterface" method="getinfo" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>

</routes>
```

**app\code\Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\TestInterface.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Sugarcode\Customapi\Api;

use Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\Data\TestdataInterface;

interface TestInterface
{
    /**
     * Retrieve list of info
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException If ID is not found
     * @return \Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\Data\TestdataInterface containing Tree objects
     */
    public function getinfo();

}
```

**don't remove comments its most important**

**app\code\Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\Data\TestdataInterface.php** (set and get data):

```
<?php

namespace Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\Data;

/**
 * @api
 */
interface TestdataInterface
{

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName();

      /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setName($id);

}
```

**app\code\Sugarcode\Customapi\Model\Test.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Sugarcode\Customapi\Model;

use Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\TestInterface;

/**
 * Defines the implementaiton class of the calculator service contract.
 */
class Test implements TestInterface
{
    /**
     * Return the sum of the two numbers.
     *
     * @api
     * @param int $num1 Left hand operand.
     * @param int $num2 Right hand operand.
     * @return int The sum of the two values.
     */
    protected $dataFactory;
    public function __construct(\Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\Data\TestdataInterfaceFactory $dataFactory)
    {
        $this->dataFactory = $dataFactory;
    }



    public function getinfo() {
        $page_object = $this->dataFactory->create();
        $page_object->setName('Hello');
        return $page_object;        

    }

}
```

**app\code\Sugarcode\Customapi\Model\Testmodel.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Sugarcode\Customapi\Model;

class Testmodel extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements
    \Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\Data\TestdataInterface 
{
    const KEY_NAME = 'name';


     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_getData(self::KEY_NAME);
    }


    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::KEY_NAME, $name);
    }


}
```

Comment: This is by far the best way to handle json key value pair response. I know you have another solution here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94618/how-to-get-mixed-or-multi-array-response-in-rest-api-magento2 but it seems not a natural approach. Thank you.

Comment: This is creating issue on magento upgrade time

Answer (score 9):

Response format (XML or JSON) is selected based on `Accept` header, set it to `application/json` on the client side.

Comment: :- if i put api url (get method )in browser it coming in xml format, how to make it in json format is there any option to set response format

Comment: If you need this just for testing/dev purposes, remove all renderers except for JSON in `Magento/Webapi/etc/di.xml`. Otherwise use some plugin for browser to set proper headers (e.g. REST client for Firefox). Anyway, it is possible to access only 'anonymous' resources without `Authorization` header.

Comment: is it mandatory api/data for node that i in array i want to key pair value in that case how to do with out data folder

Comment: Not sure I understand what you ask, please clarify.

Comment: when i call my api i need response in key value pair , for that in core module they wrote api/data interface , with out that can we end back response with key pair value as like above screen shot of categories

Comment: Data interface must be created. Its getters names will be converted into keys in the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33275/discussion-between-pradeep-kumar-and-alex-paliarush).

Comment: @PradeepKumar Is it possible to build that data interface without a getter method for every field? (What can you do when you have, for example, 200 fields? or dynamic number of fields?)

Answer (score 4):

Use a cURL :

```
    $URL = curl_init( $www );
    curl_setopt( $URL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $URL, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET" );
    curl_setopt( $URL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $URL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer " . $token_API
    ) );
```

In this step on `json_decode()` PHP function, the second paramter `true` returns JSON in array fortmat, see more: http://php.net/json_decode

```
$URL = json_decode(curl_exec($URL), true);
```

And then:

```
curl_close( $URL ); //close cURL conn

print_r( $URL ); //result
```

Comment: how can i get this  $token_API  of customer programmatically?

Comment: @Newbie 
Get an admin token POST /V1/integration/admin/token integrationAdminTokenServiceV1

Get a customer token POST /V1/integration/customer/token integrationCustomerTokenServiceV1

If you get this programmatucally create a PHP Script and request from API URL land Take a Return Value From WEB API.

Font: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using a light REST client over a browser. If you have chrome installed just install the "postman extension". There you can choose in which representation you want to see the answer.
[image]