# how to get mixed or multi array response in rest API magento2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, magento-2.0

i have my custom api which will return multi dimension array , which will have key pair value,  where key and value are dynamic from database in that case how to achieve in rest api of magento2

Answer (score 4):

to achieve multi dimension array where key and value are dynamic we can follow below steps but magento discourage this solution if any better solution please let me know 
out put

```
{
"name": "Test Name"
"key": "value"
"key2": "value2"
"multi": {
"name": "Test Name"
"key": "value"
"key2": "value2"
}-
}
```

where key and value are from db or dynamic

to create custom api follow my post in [How do I get a response from REST API in JSON format in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94492/how-do-i-get-a-response-from-rest-api-in-json-format-in-magento-2/94532#94532)

and do the below changes

in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceOutputProcessor" type="Sugarcode\Customapi\Model\ServiceOutputProcessor" />

    <preference for="Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\TestInterface"
                type="Sugarcode\Customapi\Model\Test" />

    <preference for="Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\Data\TestdataInterface" type="Sugarcode\Customapi\Model\Testmodel" />
</config>
```

app\code\Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\TestInterface.php

use @return array (which i not allowed in magento2 default ) that is

```
<?php


namespace Sugarcode\Customapi\Api;

use Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\Data\TestdataInterface;

interface TestInterface
{
    /**
     * Retrieve list of info
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException If ID is not found
     * @return array
     */
    public function getinfo();

}
```

app\code\Sugarcode\Customapi\Model\Test.php

```
public function getinfo() {
        $page_object = $this->dataFactory->create();
        $page_object->setName('eee');
        $page_object->setExtData(['key'=>'value', 'key2'=>'value2']);
        //return $page_object;
        return ['name'=>'Test Name','key'=>'value', 'key2'=>'value2',
            'multi'=>['name'=>'Test Name','key'=>'value', 'key2'=>'value2']
        ];      

    }
```

app\code\Sugarcode\Customapi\Model\ServiceOutputProcessor.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Sugarcode\Customapi\Model;;


/**
 * Data object converter for REST
 */
class ServiceOutputProcessor  extends \Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceOutputProcessor
{

     */
    public function process($data, $serviceClassName, $serviceMethodName)
    {
        /** @var string $dataType */
        $dataType = $this->methodsMapProcessor->getMethodReturnType($serviceClassName, $serviceMethodName);
        if($dataType == 'array'){
            return $data;           
        }else{
            return $this->convertValue($data, $dataType);

        }
    }


}
```

**if any better solution guy please post**

Comment: Use `mixed` return type instead of introducing new `array` type with custom processing, result should be the same.

Comment: @ale:- there i no mixed type if i used mixed then through error

Comment: There is, and it is even used in core already, see `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\TransactionInterface::setAdditionalInformation`. Also check `\Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor::ANY_TYPE`. The only difference, in your case it is as `@return`, not `@param`. Try to specify it for some param, to verify if it works for you in this case.

Comment: but array of array i not possible in that case

Comment: Try `mixed[]` for now. Also consider creating pull request with the proposed improvement on Magento 2 github (`\Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor::processSimpleAndAnyType` is a good starting point for improving current behavior)

Comment: @AlexPaliarush since Magento 2.2 mixed does not seem to work any more.

Answer (score 1):

I am using mixed for the time being. It takes an array of objects just fine. I did not need to use the bracket notation indicating an array of things.

```
@param mixed
```

Comment: This actually does not seem to work any more in Magento 2.2. Instead it seems to do a json_encode on your return type to return a string..

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is quite old, I was stumbling across the same issue. I solved it by using a new class and define that class in the annotations of the method in the interface.

So ...

Create a new Interface like the file  `Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\Data\MainDataInterface\InfoListInterface`

```
<?php    
namespace Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\Data\MainDataInterface;

interface InfoListInterface
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName();

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValue();

}
```

Then your main interface for the data object of the response should look like:

```
<?php    
namespace Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\Data;

interface MainDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Retrieve list of info
     *
     * @return \Sugarcode\Customapi\Api\Data\MainDataInterface\InfoListInterface[]
     */
    public function getInfo();

    /**
     * @param array
     */
    public function setInfo(array $infoList);

}
```

Create classes that implement those interfaces.

In your script to populate the data-objects, there should be something like ... (of course that can be realised through various methods)

```
...

public function receiveInfos() {

    ...

    $infoListArr[] = $infoListFactory->create()
        ->setData('name','name1')
        ->setData('value','value1');

    $infoListArr[] = $infoListFactory->create()
        ->setData('name','name2')
        ->setData('value','value2');        

    $mainData = $MainDataFactory->create();
    $mainData->setInfo($infoListArr);

    ...
    return $mainData;
}
```

Then for the api-request, you will receive:

```
{
   "info": [
      {
         "name","name1"
         "value","value1"
      },
      {
         "name","name2"
         "value","value2"
      }
   ]
}
```

With this method, you also have a correct swagger documentation, when going on www.yourmagentoshop.com/swagger

Comment: This answer actually works